# Ruby Array of Arrays Group and Count by Values

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to get a Ruby Array of Arrays and group it in order to count its values.

The Array has a month, and a boolean:

```
array = [["June", false], ["June", false], ["June", false], ["October", false]]
```

I will like to end with a new Array that let me know how many false vs trues in each month.

Example: (where the first item in the Array is month, the second is the count of false and the third is the count of true)

```
new_array = [["June", 3, 0]], ["October", 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
Array.group_by { |month, b| month }.map{ |month, xs|
  [month,
   xs.count {|_, b| !b},  # false
   xs.count {|_, b| b}]   # true
}
# => [["June", 3, 0], ["October", 1, 0]]
```

Comment: `Enumerable#group_by` returns a Hash, not an Array.

Comment: @Jordan, That's why I chained the return value with `map` call. (and need further processing to count `true`, `false`s)

Comment: Ah, so you did. My bad.

Comment: Nice...hope to keep learning and understand 100% how you did that :)

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable#group_by` is a useful tool, but in this case it's not the best one.

If we start with a Hash whose default value is `[0, 0]` we can do (almost) everything—look up the month (or get the default value of it's a new month) and add 1 to the appropriate index (`0` for false and `1` for true)—in a single step:

```
array = [["June", false], ["June", false], ["June", false], ["October", false]]

hsh = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [0,0] }
array.each {|mo, bool| hsh[mo][bool ? 1 : 0] += 1 }

p hsh.map(&:flatten)
# => [["June", 3, 0], ["October", 1, 0]]
```

Comment: This works as well. Why it is better that Enumerable#group_by?

Comment: With `group_by` we have to iterate over the data four times: Once to do the grouping, once to count the `true`s, once more for the `false`s, and then again to turn the Hash into an Array. With the above, we only have to iterate twice: Once to do the counting and once to turn it into an Array.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.map(&:dup) # we’ll mutate it
     .group_by(&:shift)
     .flat_map { |k, v| [k, v.partition { |e| e }.map(&:count)] }
#⇒ [ ['June', [0, 3] ], ['October', [0, 1] ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would make a good use case for a `reduce` operation. You would do something like:

```
arr = [["June", false], ["June", false], ["June", false], ["October", false]]
logical_group = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }

arr.reduce(logical_group) do |red, ele|
  red[ele.first][:false_count] += 1 unless ele.last
  red[ele.first][:true_count] += 1 if ele.last
  red
end.reduce([]) do |red, (key, value)|
  red << [key, value[:false_count], value[:true_count]]
  red
end
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Array.group_by {|(Array, boolean)| Array }.map {|Array, match| [Array, match.count] }
```

Comment: Did you try this code before you posted it? Are you aware that it doesn't work?

Comment: It throws the following error: formal argument cannot be a constant